# Tensorflow/keras - find positions of unique elements in tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to find the positions of all the different values in a 2-D tensor. Let's say that I have the following tensor:

```
spMap4x4 = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 3, 3]])
```

and I want to find the positions of elements equal to 1, then the positions of elements equal to 2 and finally, the positions of elements equal to 3 without knowing these values beforehand.

My idea was to use the "[tf.unique_with_counts](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts)" after having reshaped spMap4x4 to a 1-D tensor:

```
spMapFlatten = tf.reshape(spMap4x4, [-1])
y, idx, count = tf.unique_with_counts(spMapFlatten)
```

then, use "[tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)" to get the positions I need. For example:

```
a = tf.where(tf.equal(spMap4x4, y[0])
K.eval(a)
```

which gives here:

```
a = [[0 0]
     [1 0]
     [1 1]
     [2 0]
     [3 0]
     [3 1]]
```

The problem is, how can I do that for all the different values in y without knowing what these values are? This will be included in a keras layer so, I need a general solution.

Comment: Are the inputs sorted such that the numbers are always increasing for example?

Comment: @nuric, no, the numbers are not always increasing, it can be random

Answer (score 0):

A solution coming to mind would be to use [`tf.dynamic_partition()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_partition), but it requires you know the max number of partitions you may have (i.e. the max number of unique values in your input tensor):

```python
import tensorflow as tf

spMap4x4 = tf.constant([[1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 3, 3]])

# Requirement: knowing the max number of different values (partitions) your tensor may have
max_diff_values = 4

spMap4x4_shape = tf.shape(spMap4x4)
# Getting unique values and their reverse indices / partitions:
unique_val, unique_idx = tf.unique(tf.reshape(spMap4x4, [-1]))
unique_idx = tf.reshape(unique_idx, spMap4x4_shape)

# Building an index matrix:
idx_cols, idx_rows = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(spMap4x4_shape[0]), tf.range(spMap4x4_shape[1]))
idx_grid = tf.stack([idx_rows, idx_cols], -1)

# Partitioning the index matrix according to the unique values' partitions:
partitioned_idx = tf.dynamic_partition(idx_grid, unique_idx, num_partitions=max_diff_values)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(partitioned_idx))
    # [array([[0, 0],
    #         [1, 0],
    #         [1, 1],
    #         [2, 0],
    #         [3, 0],
    #         [3, 1]], dtype=int32),
    #  array([[0, 1],
    #         [0, 2],
    #         [0, 3],
    #         [1, 2]], dtype=int32), 
    #  array([[1, 3],
    #         [2, 1],
    #         [2, 2],
    #         [2, 3],
    #         [3, 2],
    #         [3, 3]], dtype=int32), 
    #  array( [], shape=(0, 2), dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: Thanks @Aldream, I guess I could count the number of different values beforehand and give it to the layer.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution, but I can't think of another one right now (e.g. `tf.while_loop()` and `tf.map_fn()` can't be used since your output positions-per-value tensors would have different shapes...).